# moving the file from one folder to another folder

Tags: bash

I have got 2 folder in the same directory ie

directory exp

folders name data ,log.

I wold like to write the bash script so that when I click on move .sh file then content of data folder should move to log folder and name of the file in data folder should go to another file i.e filenames.txt which is also present in exp directory

Comment: the similar script for window which i wrote is if exist "%EXP_PATH%\data\*.*" goto found
echo no *.csv files found.
goto end

:found

rem delete filename file
del %EXP_PATH%\filenames.txt


cd %EXP_PATH%\data

rem to get all the *.csv files inside the directory
For %%x in (exp*.*) do echo %%x>>%EXP_PATH%\filenames.txt
:end

Comment: Umair Khan, there is not batch on Ubuntu here is shell or bash Scripting.

Comment: Use python if you want to take it easy on Linux.

Comment: I am new to ubuntu . i want the exact code for ubuntu which i wrote for windows in previous comment. can you help me out?

Comment: What do you meant by "click"..does it mean you want to execute `move.sh` ?

Comment: i should have a  executable file move.sh in desktop and when i click on that icon the file should move

Comment: @Umairkhan Did you try the answer below?

Comment: yeah ..its not moving.....

Answer (score 1):

Provided there are no duplicate file names, the following is a simple script that will do what you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls <path-to-data-folder> >> <path-to-filenames.txt>
mv <path-to-data-folder>/* <path-to-log-folder>
```

Plug-in the actual path to your folders/files.
Save it as move.sh, make it executable by `chmod +x <path-to-move.sh>` and run it.

To run it on clicking, first right click on `move.sh` click properties and then go to permission tab and click on "Allow executing file as program" as shown below:
[image]

Close it and then go to Edit -> Preferences->Behaviour in nautilus and click on "Run executable text files when they are opened" as shown below:
[image]

Close it.

Now if you can run the script by just double-clicking on `move.sh`.

Comment: you stole my answer :-)

Comment: nope, I made my answer better (check the time)  :P

Answer (score -1):

first thing you need to do is make nautilus (your file explorer) to run executable files on double clicking (**NOTE**: you must be careful when you are running executable file downloaded from internet)

1. Open Nautilus (by clicking icon on the launcher)
2. In menu bar click on `Edit`
3. then look for a tab called `Behaviour`
4. under `Executable Text Files` select `Ask each time`. (**NOTE**: you can select `Run executable text files when they are opened`, but its recommended not to choose this option because you might run a executable file by mistake)

then make `move.sh` file in directory `exp`, its content will be:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -1 data >> filenames.txt
mv -t log ./data/*
```

(you can use gedit to copy paste these above lines and save the file in `exp` directory)
then open terminal and run:

```
cd exp
chmod u+x move.sh
```

Done!

Comment: what is `move -t`?